# Cocoapods parsing error

Tags: cocoapods

I am stuck by this error ,please help to find out this
This error occur when update Cocoa pods,

> [!] ERROR: Parsing unable to continue due to parsing error:
>       contained in the file located at /Users/macadmin/Desktop/Podfile.lock
>       PODS:
>         - Braintree (4.7.0):
>           - Braintree/Card (= 4.7.0)
>           - Braintree/Core (= 4.7.0)
>           - Braintree/PayPal (= 4.7.0)
>           - Braintree/UI (= 4.7.0)
>         - Braintree/Card (4.7.0):
>           - Braintree/Core
>         - Braintree/Core (4.7.0)
>         - Braintree/PayPal (4.7.0):
>           - Braintree/Core
>           - Braintree/PayPalOneTouch
>         - Braintree/PayPalDataCollector (4.7.0):
>           - Braintree/Core
>           - Braintree/PayPalUtils
>         - Braintree/PayPalOneTouch (4.7.0):
>           - Braintree/Core
>           - Braintree/PayPalDataCollector
>           - Braintree/PayPalUtils
>         - Braintree/PayPalUtils (4.7.0)
>         - Braintree/UI (4.7.0):
>           - Braintree/Card
>           - Braintree/Core
>         - Firebase (3.7.1):
>           - Firebase/Core (= 3.7.1)
>         - Firebase/Auth (3.7.1):
>           - Firebase/Core
>           - FirebaseAuth (= 3.0.5)
>         - Firebase/Core (3.7.1):
>           - FirebaseAnalytics (= 3.4.4)
>           - FirebaseCore (= 3.4.3)
>         - Firebase/Database (3.7.1):
>           - Firebase/Core
>           - FirebaseDatabase (= 3.0.3)
>         - Firebase/Messaging (3.7.1):
>           - Firebase/Core
>           - FirebaseMessaging (= 1.2.0)
>         - FirebaseAnalytics (3.4.4):
>           - FirebaseCore (~> 3.4)
>           - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 1.0)
>           - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (~> 1.2)
>           - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
>         - FirebaseAuth (3.0.5):
>           - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 3.3)
>           - GoogleNetworkingUtilities (~> 1.2)
>           - GoogleUtilities (~> 1.2)
>         - FirebaseCore (3.4.3):
>           - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (~> 1.2)
>           - GoogleUtilities (~> 1.2)
>         - FirebaseDatabase (3.0.3):
>           - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 3.3)
>         - FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.8)
>         - FirebaseMessaging (1.2.0):
>           - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 3.3)
>           - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 1.0)
>           - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (~> 1.2)
>           - GoogleIPhoneUtilities (~> 1.2)
>           - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
>         - GoogleAppUtilities (1.1.2):
>           - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
>         - GoogleAuthUtilities (2.0.2):
>           - GoogleNetworkingUtilities (~> 1.2)
>           - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
>         - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.2):
>           - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
>         - GoogleIPhoneUtilities (1.2.1):
>           - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.0)
>           - GoogleUtilities (~> 1.0)
>         - GoogleMaps (2.1.0):
>           - GoogleMaps/Maps (= 2.1.0)
>         - GoogleMaps/Base (2.1.0)
>         - GoogleMaps/Maps (2.1.0):
>           - GoogleMaps/Base (= 2.1.0)
>         - GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.2.2):
>           - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
>         - GooglePlacePicker (2.1.0):
>           - GoogleMaps (= 2.1.0)
>           - GooglePlaces (= 2.1.0)
>         - GooglePlaces (2.1.0):
>           - GoogleMaps/Base (= 2.1.0)
>         - GoogleSignIn (4.0.0):
>           - GoogleAppUtilities (~> 1.1)
>           - GoogleAuthUtilities (~> 2.0)
>           - GoogleNetworkingUtilities (~> 1.2)
>           - GoogleUtilities (~> 1.3)
>         - GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
>         - GoogleUtilities (1.3.2):
>           - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
>         - KeychainSwift (6.0.2)
>         - ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK (3.0.1)
>         - SwiftHTTP (1.0.6)
>         - SwiftyJSON (3.1.1)
>         - TwilioSDK (1.2.11)
>
> ```
> DEPENDENCIES:
>   - Braintree
>   - Firebase (>= 2.5.1)
>   - Firebase/Auth
>   - Firebase/Core
>   - Firebase/Database
>   - Firebase/Messaging
>   - GoogleMaps
>   - GooglePlacePicker
>   - GooglePlaces
>   - GoogleSignIn
>   - KeychainSwift (~> 6.0)
>   - ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK
>   - SwiftHTTP (~> 1.0.4)
>   - SwiftyJSON (from `https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git`)
>   - TwilioSDK (~> 1.2)
>
> EXTERNAL SOURCES:
>   SwiftyJSON:
>     :git: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git
>
> CHECKOUT OPTIONS:
>   SwiftyJSON:
>     :commit: 5a5928b5a021e140409e8bd20244d41dbba6c52d
>     :git: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git
>
> SPEC CHECKSUMS:
>   Braintree: 2d53c805e93a5830a4359a757be50fc0f25392a9
>   Firebase: be473484f0d515e72ffd04acf22f981773c23e58
>   FirebaseAnalytics: 0533a00b681e08fd0b2cd0444b7ddf0ef9fd7a1a
>   FirebaseAuth: 75a062bbf2d3c97d1e6e55bbc110e13a6853e25d
>   FirebaseCore: 5a885548bbc5f0c410b04f8e9ac9d73ff1221907
>   FirebaseDatabase: 750a4a0fe18ef114318876fd654b2d9c671e0992
>   FirebaseInstanceID: ba1e640935235e5fac39dfa816fe7660e72e1a8a
>   FirebaseMessaging: 789d23fd796594dfb55dcf36cd325541df887c22
>   GoogleAppUtilities: a8a552aa74f6597f805e45b5a3962766c3134973
>   GoogleAuthUtilities: ccad2e0a9284699973ff57c0dd24c3893657fda4
>   GoogleInterchangeUtilities: d5bc4d88d5b661ab72f9d70c58d02ca8c27ad1f7
>   GoogleIPhoneUtilities: 63f25e93a3ddcb66884d182aab3a660d98f1479b
>   GoogleMaps: 06589b9a38097bce0cd6e90f0fd9b5e4b4a9344c
>   GoogleNetworkingUtilities: 3edd3a8161347494f2da60ea0deddc8a472d94cb
>   GooglePlacePicker: a2228b447d10008bcb765a6a081f415e8599e5d4
>   GooglePlaces: 16e96266483b8010e9f275399403647978523c86
>   GoogleSignIn: 09036ed61f8e75f1424100d63f7719480b2428c3
>   GoogleSymbolUtilities: 631ee17048aa5e9ab133470d768ea997a5ef9b96
>   GoogleUtilities: 8bbc733218aad26306f9d4a253823986110e3358
>   KeychainSwift: a261364334000afa8fab0894390d5d00dd226d4c
>   ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK: ba5955ffdbe9286caf238c661cdab1c66de9c0f6
>   SwiftHTTP: e9124c24b3cff5138d0fb6c5481192ee198a4c0b
>   SwiftyJSON: f0be2e604f83e8405a624e9f891898bf6ed4e019
>   TwilioSDK: c1efd3b273c243b5a034baa0d29ad370afb893d9
>
> COCOAPODS: 0.39.0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to occur because of a problem with psych. See this thread for a complete discussion: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3466

**Short Answer:** `gem uninstall psych`

This should leave you with an older version of psych, in my case, v2.0.8.

Use gem list to confirm, as anything greater, based on the discussion at github, seems to break the Podfile parsing.